# the code of local Search engine wouldn't work

Tags: html, css, local

that (https:// jsfiddle . net /a0t376hy/)

Contains software codes local search, does not want to work after repeatedly tried installed correctly, what reason?

Comment: Include relevant code in the question, not only at an external site. As I'm sure you were pointed out to when trying to post with only the link.

Comment: I'm having problems, I could barely type the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map fields in the JSON to the expected column name.

```
    fields: {
      title   : 'name'
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0t376hy/2/

Comment: i know, but the problem there is no pop-up window when you type any word in the search box!

i creat 1- css folder inside it has style.css. 2- js folder inside it has main.js. and in the main has index.html. and i put the codes!, but the probleme nothing scroll when i write anything!? @jonasnas

Comment: i understand now, but how i can do that?, would you do it for me?